# Best way to continue to query Quickbooks data

Tags: quickbooks

I have a problem with the qbxml.

I'm trying to migrate the qb customers, items etc to zohobooks. 
I want to grab 50 customers first from quickbooks and calling zohobooks apis to create contacts on there. and again another 50 customers from quickbooks and to zohobooks.

The problem is I'm sure how can I continue to query after calling the zohobooks apis?

When I tried to use the same iteratorID from the first query response I got nothing from QB.

I'm building desktop app using .net, please advise me the best option to track the migration and where I'm.

Assume that I have 150 customers and for some reason stopped migrating after 100customers, in this case how can I get the last 50 customers next time?

```
public string customerQueryXml()
{
    XmlDocument inputXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
    inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null));
    inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("qbposxml", "version=\"1.0\""));

    XmlElement qbXML = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("QBPOSXML");
    inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(qbXML);

    XmlElement qbXMLMsgsRq = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("QBPOSXMLMsgsRq");
    qbXML.AppendChild(qbXMLMsgsRq);
    qbXMLMsgsRq.SetAttribute("onError", "stopOnError");

    XmlElement customerQueryRq = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("CustomerQueryRq");
    qbXMLMsgsRq.AppendChild(customerQueryRq);
    //customerQueryRq.SetAttribute("requestID", "1");
    //customerQueryRq.SetAttribute("iterator", "Start");
    customerQueryRq.SetAttribute("requestID", "2");
    customerQueryRq.SetAttribute("iterator", "Continue");
    customerQueryRq.SetAttribute("iteratorID", "{A1601C19-C6DC-43C0-AE43-6F45088C39F2}");


    // for test only, read 10 customers
    XmlElement MaxReturned = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("MaxReturned");
    customerQueryRq.AppendChild(MaxReturned).InnerText = "50";

    XmlElement ownerID = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("OwnerID");
    customerQueryRq.AppendChild(ownerID).InnerText = "0";

    XmlElement timeModifiedRangeFilter = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("TimeModifiedRangeFilter");
    customerQueryRq.AppendChild(timeModifiedRangeFilter);

    XmlElement fromTimeModified = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("FromTimeModified");
    timeModifiedRangeFilter.AppendChild(fromTimeModified).InnerText = "1980-01-01T00:00:00";

    XmlElement toTimeModified = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("ToTimeModified");
    timeModifiedRangeFilter.AppendChild(toTimeModified).InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");

    return inputXMLDoc.OuterXml;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I noticed that I have to use the iteratorID in the same request. By the way I have no problem with the qbxml itself. 
My question is how can I continue to query the customers, items or whatever on another request?

- ProcessRequest (first time)
- migrated xml data to another system
- and after that for whatever reason I stopped the request
- here, can I continue to query on another ProcessRequest?

Comment: Iterators are the normal way to handle this. If you're having problems with them, you should post the qbXML requests and responses to/from QuickBooks, so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. I just want to know how can I continue query customers on another request. Please check my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators have to be used within a single `Session`. e.g. this will work:

- Connect to QuickBooks (establish a session)
- Do a request to create an iterator and get the first page of records
- Do another request to continue the iterator
- Do another request to continue the iterator

While this will *not* work, and is *not* something supported by QuickBooks:

- Connect to QuickBooks (establish a session)
- Do a request to create an iterator and get the first page of records
- Disconnect
- Do a request to create an iterator and get the first page of records

Comment: you mean, I can't continue query on another session, right?

Comment: I checked the php devkit you wrote, it seems you used date as a filter to continue.

Comment: Correct, you can not continue a query on a different session than the query was started on. If I used a date as a filter to continue, then it's a mistaken (and you should drop a link here, so it can be fixed).

Comment: For example on this file https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/3df0d35e2fc04c1fe04c63dbdb3c11a501c305a1/docs/web_connector/example_web_connector_import.php#L766, for FromModifiedDate field you used $last. I think this is the best way to track newly added transaction data or items etc. Is this a mistaken?

Comment: Yes, that is the best way to track newly added data. However, note that that is SEPARATE FROM continuing an existing query. e.g. You can use a filter and NOT continue a query. You can continue a query and NOT use a filter. Or you can use a filter AND continue a query. They are two separate things, which you can optionally use together, but continuing a query is _not_ necessarily tied to using a filter at all.